# Programatically insert gif/image into facebook chat from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I'm trying to programatically inject an image into facebook chat via javascript and send it to the person I'm chatting with (jQuery is ok, but I'd rather avoid it). I have the image in a javascript var and I'd like to avoid using facebook APIs (if there is any for this, I didn't find anything). The problem is that facebook keeps changing ids of divs in html and their js is obfuscated, so I can't gather much from there.

It seems that class "_1ia" is always the same for the element on which the drag n drop is carried out, so I can grab it with
`document.getElementByClass('_1ia');`

Answer (score 1):

The Chat API does not exist anymore, and everything else would not be allowed because that would be scraping. In other words: it´s not possible.

You may want to take a look at the new Messenger platform: https://www.messenger.com/platform

Comment: I guessed as much, but for the sake of learning, how would it be done?

Comment: i´m sorry, but we do not discuss illegal stuff on stackoverflow. i hope you understand, it´s pointless anyway - if it´s not allowed, don´t do it ;)

Comment: i´ve added a link to my answer that may be interesting for you

Comment: I would recommend you also find out the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797896/why-some-gif-animation-link-does-not-animate-in-facebook voteup,strange behaviour on facebook with gifs

Comment: @Axil: that´s completely unrelated to this topic, please don´t hijack threads.